Moduli Stack of Formal Groups Rationally
I have little experience with algebraic geometry but it seems relevant to understand homotopy theory, so I'm grateful to any pointer on how to understand the following rigorously.
I'd like to understand how to obtain the following assertion in Lurie's notes on chromatic homotopy theory rigorously:

Corollary 12.2. The quotient stack $\mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{FG}}^s \times \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Q}} = [\operatorname{\operatorname{Spec}}{L}/G] \times \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Q}}$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Let me briefly recall the notation.
Let $\mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{FG}}^s = [\operatorname{Spec}{L}/G]$ denote the moduli stack of formal groups with strict isomorphism.

Here, $L$ is the Lazard ring, defined by the universal property that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{CRing}}(L, R) \cong \mathsf{FGL}(R)$, i.e. the universal ring carrying a universal formal group law (power series with group-like properties).
And $G = \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Z}[b_1, b_2, \cdots]}$ representing strict automorphisms of formal group laws, i.e. its $R$-valued points are power series $g(t) = t+b_1 t^2 + b_2 t^3 + \cdots \in R[[t]]$ and the group operation is given by composition of power series.

Briefly, it is also the functor $\mathsf{CRing}^{\mathsf{op}} \to \mathsf{Grpd}, \ R \mapsto (\mathsf{FGL}(R), \text{strict isomorphisms})$.
The result makes sense intuitively: We already the the following result.

Proposition 12.1. Let $R \in \mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Then, for every formal group law $f \in R [[x,y]]$ there exists a unique power series $g(t) = t + b_1 t^2 + b_2 t^3 + \cdots \in R[[t]]$ such that $f(x,y) = g(g^{-1}(x) + g^{-1}(y))$.

In other words, every formal group law is rationally isomorphic to the additive formal group law via a strict isomorphism $g$. How do I translate this intuitive argument into a rigorous argument with quotient stacks?

Actually, having written the question, the argument should probably go along the following lines: We have $\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}{R}, \mathcal{M}{\mathrm{FG}}^s \times \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Q}}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}{R}, \mathcal{M}{\mathrm{FG}}^s) \times \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec}{R}, \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Q}})$. If the second factor is supposed to be non-empty, then $R$ must be an $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. Then, the first factor is essentially just one point by the cited proposition.

So maybe the question is obsolete now... (still good for me!). Any comment is still welcome.

Let $\mathsf{Stk}$ be the $\infty$-category of stacks.
We compute
$$
   \operatorname{Map}_{\mathsf{Stk}}(\operatorname{Spec}{R}, \mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{FG}}^s \times \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Q}) \cong \operatorname{Map}_{\mathsf{Stk}}(\operatorname{Spec}{R}, \mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{FG}}^s) \times \operatorname{Map}_{\mathsf{Stk}}(\operatorname{Spec}{R}, \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Q}).
  $$
We need to show that this is naturally isomorphic to $\operatorname{Map}_{\mathsf{Stk}}(\operatorname{Spec}{R}, \operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb Q})$. If it is empty, then this is true. Otherwise, there exists a map $\mathbb Q \to R$, i.e. $R \in \mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb Q}$, but then $\operatorname{Map}_{\mathsf{Stk}}(\operatorname{Spec}{R}, \mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{FG}}^s) \simeq *$ by the rational discussion of formal group laws (Proposition 12.1).
